# SurveyJS Not Displaying

Tags: laravel, vue.js, surveyjs

Trying to use surveyjs with laravel and vue, but when I try to get the survey from a api does not work.
I'm getting the data from a api in laravel controller.

[image]

surveyshow.vue

```
<template>    
    <div>
        <survey :survey="survey"></survey>
    </div>
</template>  


created () {
...
  let url = `/api/edit/i130`;
         
             axios
                .get(url)
                .then(response => {
                     surveyJson = JSON.parse(response.data.data.json);
                     console.log(JSON.parse(response.data.data.json));
        
                })
                 .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        this.survey  = new SurveyVue.Model(surveyJson);
```

if I replace the variable using a constant works.

```
          var  surveyJson = {
   
    pages: [
        {
            "name": "Address",
            "title": "Address",
            "questions": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "name": "address1",
                    "title": "Street Address",
                    "autocompleteAs": "placeautocomplete"
                }, {
                    "type": "text",
                    "name": "address2",
                    "title": "Address Line 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the asynchronous aspect of your code. There is a callback function, which runs when the request to your api completes:

```
...
.then(response => {
       surveyJson = JSON.parse(response.data.data.json);
       console.log(JSON.parse(response.data.data.json));
    })
...
```

but you are trying to load the survey json "outside" of it. In other words, this runs *before* the api request's callback has had a chance to load the survey's JSON:

```
...
this.survey  = new SurveyVue.Model(surveyJson);
...
```

You should move the line that instantiates your survey inside the callback, like this:

```
...
.then(response => {
       surveyJson = JSON.parse(response.data.data.json);
       window.survey  = new SurveyVue.Model(surveyJson);
    })
...
```